# Program not executing

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class FibonnaciSeries {

    static {
        int first = 0;
        int next = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(next);
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            sum = next + first;
            first = next;
            next = sum;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }

}
```

When I tyr to run it in Eclipse, it is not running. Why.?

Comment: Just put it in a main. Why are you putting everything in a `static` block anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Java 7`, you need to have the `main()` method, to execute a code.

Add `public static void main(String args[]) { }` to your class.

Prior to `Java 6` and below, you can add `System.exit(0);` to your static block, to make your code to execute. **(NOTE: This will not work on Eclipse. Try from command line.)**

Comment: If using `//`, the `}` shouldn't be at the end of the line (otherwise it will be part of the comment).

Answer (score 2):

Do it right -- take the code out of the static initializer block and put it in a static main block:

```
public class FibonnaciSeries {

    public static main(String[] args) {
        int first = 0;
        int next = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println(first);
        System.out.println(next);
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            sum = next + first;
            first = next;
            next = sum;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

I fear that you may be using the static initializer block because you're not fully familiar with the structure of a main method. Java programs need a starting point, a method that the JVM can identify and know that "this is the place to start running from", and that is the main method. Give your class one of these, and avoid static initializer blocks unless you know why you need to use it and are using it for this specific reason.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
public class FibonnaciSeries {

static {
    int first = 0;
    int next = 1;
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(next);
    for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        sum = next + first;
        first = next;
        next = sum;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) { } 
}
```

I tested and it worked. It require a main function to execute your class on console enviroment and you static block will be loaded.

Comment: It is better to till why it worked for you not just giving the answer